# Sending APNS by way of Node.js

Tags: node.js, apple-push-notifications

I'm following the instructions on [argon/node-apn](https://github.com/argon/node-apn) to send a message.  It seems to work fine, except unless I set up connectionTimeout to 1000, process does not return.

My question:  Should I be setting a "connectionTimeout" so the process returns and I continue with code, or should I be doing something else?

Here is my code:

```
var apn = require ('apn/index.js');

var options = {
        cert: './cert.pem',
        key: './key.pem',
        connectionTimeout: 1000,
        production: false
};
var apnConnection = new apn.Connection(options);

apnConnection.on('disconnected', function() {
    console.log("Disconnected from APNS");
});

var token       = '<my token>';

var myDevice    = new apn.Device(token);

var note = new apn.Notification();

note.expiry             = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 3600; // Expires 1 hour from now.
note.badge              = 777;
note.retryLimit         = 1;
note.sound              = "ping.aiff";
note.alert = "\u2709 Sorry ..... ";
note.payload            = {'messageFrom': 'My Payload'};

apnConnection.pushNotification(note, myDevice);
```

Comment: Did you figure it out?